# Como anidar ciclos For en una tabla

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo el siguiente codigo en Javascript:

```
     document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML=`<br><br>
        <table class="table table-dark" id="Table">
</table>`;

$("#Table").append('<tr><td align="center" style="color:#FFBD09">Palabras Clave</td>'+
'<td align="center" id="s">Sentimientos</td>' + 
'<td align="center">Conceptos</td><tr>');

        for(var i=0; i<respuestaURL.keywords.length; i++){
          for(var a=0; a<respuestaURL.concepts.length; a++){
            $("#Table").append('<tr>' + 
        '<td align="center" style="dislay: none;" id="s">'+respuestaURL.keywords[i].text+'</td>'+
                '<td align="center" style="dislay: none;" >'+respuestaURL.concepts[a].text+'</td>');
        }
      }
```

Al momento de que la tabla me muestra los resultados, me aparecen repetidos los resultados de `respuestaURL.keywords[i].text` con los de `respuestaURL.concepts[i].text`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los resultados no se repitan y si uno tiene más datos que otro en la tabla me deje algun espacio en blanco. Es decir, si en uno tengo 3 resultados y en el otro 4, que el de los 3 resultados no se repita para llenar espacio del de 4.

Me llegan 3 datos de

```
respuestaURL.keywords.length
```

que son: `Hola, mundo, hello`

y de `respuestaURL.concepts.length`
me llegan: `pastel, mundo, halo, señor`

Muchas gracias.

Comment: por lo general conviene armar todo el html de la tabla ( en un string ) antes de hacer el append ( los navegadores van a intentar cerrar etiquetas cada vez que agregas algo al DOM y a veces te complica las cosas)

Comment: ¿Cómo podría resolverlo?

Comment: algo del tipo `var tablaHTML = "<table> ..."` luego los for anidados agregando cosas `tablaHTML += "<tr>"` , `tablaHTML += "<td>" + cosas + "</td>"` y por ultimo el `tablaHTML += "</table>"` seguido del append

Comment: podes incluir un ejemplo de datos ( anonimizados ) que vienen en los keywords/concepts y cual sería el resultado esperado ? ( para dejar espacios: o pones un td vacio por cada valor faltante o le das colspan al td para que ocupe varias columnas )

Comment: Listo, lo he editado

Comment: faltaría el resultado esperado, dale al icono `<>` y te permite armar un fragmento de código donde podes poner html ( armas la tabla a mano y vemos como llegar a eso )